# Can a high number of read/write deteriorate the flash itself?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, flash-memory

On embedded microcontrollers such as STM32/ESP/ARM in general is there a deterioration problem in case of high I/O on the external flash?

i'm talking about the famous 4Mb/8Mb/16Mb QSPI flash where generally the codes resides as well.

Say that each 30 seconds i'm going to write an int for example and i do that for all the day long, will the flash die sooner or later?

In this case what is the best HW for embedded system that is capable of withstand high IO? What are the workarounds?

Comment: just read the specs on the device.  short answer yes you will wear it out.  Days or weeks or months?  have to read the specs...

Comment: the workaround is use ram it doesnt wear out like that, before the power goes down then you save state to the flash.  your system design is such that you have enough reserve power (bulk capacitance, battery, etc) to survive after you detect a power loss to the unit to save to flash/eeprom/whatever.

Comment: another alternative is just battery backed power, like our PCs use.

Comment: you have to be careful running code out of external spi flashes (not sure how you are even doing that, note arm is a core/IP not a microcontroller) you can get read disturb problems.  the memories in the mcu do not have those problems (otherwise the product would be a failure and be quickly removed from the product card).

Comment: How do you detect a system power loss if it is unexpected?

Comment: pretty simple a diode and a cap would do it.  the cap is your reserve power, the diode protects that power from heading off toward the power supply so it allows current in.  you put your sense line on the power supply side of the diode (connect it to a gpio pin), when it goes away the cap keeps the part alive, but the gpio pin changes state, interrupt on that design all of this so you know the worst case write time to the flash and have enough capacitance to hold that long plus margin.  there are more complicated ways too.

Comment: based on your title question, reads wont harm the flash like writes will it is the writes (or most likely the erase cycles) that you need to worry about.

Comment: And how do you handle 2-3/7 days of data in RAM for example? Assume that for some reason the device cannot communicate with "its network" or "its base" how do you handle that? Is that frequency of writing acceptable?

Comment: size the part appropriately.  all of this falls under the heading of system design, you have requirements, lifetime of product, data collected, what percentage stored, cost, whatever.  do your design...you want to write to flash fine, design a system that will survive that, if you need 16 flash parts so that each takes 1/16th the wear and tear so that overall the product survives, then you do that, if you need more ram to save on flash wear and tear you do that.  if you are writing software already then you have skipped 17 steps ahead. not ready for that yet.  read the manuals do the design.

Comment: so long as the solution meets the specs, then yes that is acceptable...as part of the design or preliminary design you work through the desireds and requireds, and you whittle away at those until you have your list of requireds and then you design to that insuring that you meet each one of them.  if you meet each one of them then clearly that is an acceptable product.

Comment: my guess is you dont know what the possible solutions or problems are yet and are doing research basically to learn these things and that is fine. take a flash part, write to it constantly and check it periodically, see how many hours or days before it fails.  the number in the datasheet  is the we are saying all parts will do this, some and perhaps many will go way past that, but you wont be able to test enough parts to see the overall average nor margin the vendor place, so design to the datasheet, confirm with them directly if you think it is in error.

Comment: you can try compression depending on your data, etc, maybe you already have but maybe you can reduce the number of bytes stored on flash, but do it in a lossless way, saving flash wear and tear, size of flash, etc at the expense of some more ram and instructions.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how should i design a solution to the problem of saving data semi-permanently in case i cannot use a "connection" and i'm exploring the possibility to use the flash. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's clearly not a software, but a hardware problem.

Comment: @Olaf: then rather move it to EE, because it'd be still a valid question there.

Comment: @berendi: What keeps you from mod-flagging to do so? I'm not a mod!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as the commenters have commented, it will fail eventually.  Look in the datasheet for a specification typically called "Endurance".  Common on-chip NAND flash endurance limits range from 10,000 writes to 100,000 writes, sometimes even higher, but the only numbers that matter are those in your specific part's datasheet.   Once you know the endurance, you can come up with a design that predicts a reasonable lifetime based on write size, frequency, possible compression, RAM caching, etc.

Comment: Don't answer apparent off-topic questions. This will inhibit roomba and require manual deletion. Vote to close instead!

Answer (score 1):

> Say that each 30 seconds i'm going to write an int for example and i do that >for all the day long, will the flash die sooner or later?

Look up the number of write cycles in the datasheet, and do the math. Let's say your part can endure 1000000 write cycles, then doing a write every 30 seconds will start to wear it out in 30 million seconds. A year is about 31.5 million seconds...

> In this case what is the best HW for embedded system that is capable of >withstand high IO?

Some [FRAM (Ferroelectric RAM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectric_RAM) can support up to 10<sup>12</sup> read/write cycles. It will last for 31689 years even if you are accessing it in every second. Note that reads also count, but that won't be a problem unless your device loses power and must boot up in every second.

> What are the workarounds?

Wear leveling, that's what the controllers in SD cards and SSD drives do. But you'd need a disproportionately big flash to do that for a few counters.

Some microcontrollers have a small amount of backup RAM that can be powered with a battery or supercap over a separate V<sub>bat</sub> pin. Don't forget to change the battery every few years. For the price of a battery and a socket you'd get an FRAM though.

Comment: Don't answer apparent off-topic questions. This will inhibit roomba and require manual deletion. Vote to close instead!